# Question on Julia function parameter syntax

Tags: function, syntax, julia, signature

Consider the following function signature: `function f(xs :: AbstractVector{T}, ::Val{U}, ::Val{V}) where {T, U, V}`. I understand the concept of [value types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#%22Value-types%22-1), but I'm not certain if I understand the meaning of the prepended double-colon and I can't seem to be able to find any information specifically on this subject.

In C++ similar syntax would ensure that resolution of the name occurs from the global instead of current namespace but I'm not sure this applies to Julia (and, if it does, how). I can infer that this has to do with types since the same syntax is used to denote the type of a variable but what does it mean to have a type assignment without the assignee? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function f(xs :: AbstractVector{T}, ::Val{U}, ::Val{V}) where {T, U, V}
```

means that the call to `f` must pass three arguments of types `AbstractVector`, `Val` and `Val` respectively. However, you capture the **value** of passed variable only for the first argument `xs`. The values of the second and third arguments are not captured (in this case you do not really need them as `Val` is a singleton type). But you capture types `T`, `U` and `V`, and can refer to them in the body of the function.